# TSQL: Find Date of a Previous 'Day of The Week' Logic. Are there any edge cases where this will fail and can it be simplified?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have various SSIS jobs that will run on different days of the week and need to reference if a previous job has run (via log table timestamp) prior to it running.  Since there are various schedules for each job type (depends on 3rd party integration needs), I wanted to have a universal script to set some variables which could be selectively referenced in each script as needed.

For instance, "On every other Wednesday, 'Job A' runs and staggered on every other Wednesday, 'Job B' runs.  I need to NOT run 'Job B' if 'Job A' didn't run (leave a log timestamp of its running) the previous Wednesday."

So, I've searched many different approaches and below is what I came up with:

```
-- Sets the first day of the week to Monday (used in finding 'previous day' below)
SET DATEFIRST 1

DECLARE
    @DATE_TIME      SMALLDATETIME
,   @LastWeekMon    SMALLDATETIME
,   @LastWeekTue    SMALLDATETIME
,   @LastWeekWed    SMALLDATETIME
,   @LastWeekThu    SMALLDATETIME
,   @LastWeekFri    SMALLDATETIME
,   @LastWeekSat    SMALLDATETIME
,   @LastWeekSun    SMALLDATETIME
,   @PrevMon        SMALLDATETIME
,   @PrevTue        SMALLDATETIME
,   @PrevWed        SMALLDATETIME
,   @PrevThu        SMALLDATETIME
,   @PrevFri        SMALLDATETIME
,   @PrevSat        SMALLDATETIME
,   @PrevSun        SMALLDATETIME
,   @DontAllowPrevToBeToday BIT
,   @DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST INT

--SET CONSTANTS
--SET @DATE_TIME = GETDATE();
SET @DATE_TIME = '2018-07-21 00:00:00';
SET @DontAllowPrevToBeToday = 1; --true

select @DATE_TIME as DATE_TIME

-----------------------------------------

--GET LAST WEEK'S DAY-OF-THE-WEEK DATE (REGARDLESS OF SYSTEM ZERO DATE AND DATEFIRST SETTINGS)
SELECT @LastWeekMon = DATEADD(week,
       DATEDIFF(week,'19000101',@DATE_TIME),'1899-12-25T00:00:00')  --12/25/1899 is a Monday

SELECT @LastWeekTue = DATEADD(week,
       DATEDIFF(week,'19000101',@DATE_TIME),'1899-12-26T00:00:00')  --12/26/1899 is a Tuesday

SELECT @LastWeekWed = DATEADD(week,
       DATEDIFF(week,'19000101',@DATE_TIME),'1899-12-27T00:00:00')  --12/27/1899 is a Wednesday

SELECT @LastWeekThu = DATEADD(week,
       DATEDIFF(week,'19000101',@DATE_TIME),'1899-12-28T00:00:00')  --12/28/1899 is a Thursday

SELECT @LastWeekFri = DATEADD(week,
       DATEDIFF(week,'19000101',@DATE_TIME),'1899-12-29T00:00:00')  --12/29/1899 is a Friday

SELECT @LastWeekSat = DATEADD(week,
       DATEDIFF(week,'19000101',@DATE_TIME),'1899-12-30T00:00:00')  --12/30/1899 is a Saturday

SELECT @LastWeekSun = DATEADD(week,
       DATEDIFF(week,'19000101',@DATE_TIME),'1899-12-31T00:00:00')  --12/31/1899 is a Sunday

SELECT @LastWeekMon as LastWeekMon, @LastWeekTue as LastWeekTue, @LastWeekWed as LastWeekWed, @LastWeekThu as LastWeekThu, @LastWeekFri as LastWeekFri, @LastWeekSat as LastWeekSat, @LastWeekSun as LastWeekSun

-----------------------------------------

SET @DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST = DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) + -(0); --Mon + 0 = 1 = Monday
SELECT @PrevMon =
    CASE
        WHEN @DontAllowPrevToBeToday = 1 And DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0) THEN
            --PREV DAY IS TODAY, USE DAY FROM LAST WEEK
            @LastWeekMon
        ELSE
            --PREV DAY SELECT
            DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0)
    END

SET @DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST = DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) + -(1); --Mon + 1 = 2 = Tuesday
SELECT @PrevTue =
    CASE
        WHEN @DontAllowPrevToBeToday = 1 And DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0) THEN
            --PREV DAY IS TODAY, USE DAY FROM LAST WEEK
            @LastWeekTue
        ELSE
            --PREV DAY SELECT
            DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0)
    END


SET @DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST = DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) + -(2); --Mon + 2 = 3 = Wednesday
SELECT @PrevWed =
    CASE
        WHEN @DontAllowPrevToBeToday = 1 And DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0) THEN
            --PREV DAY IS TODAY, USE DAY FROM LAST WEEK
            @LastWeekWed
        ELSE
            --PREV DAY SELECT
            DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0)
    END

SET @DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST = DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) + -(3); --Mon + 3 = 4 = Thursday
SELECT @PrevThu =
    CASE
        WHEN @DontAllowPrevToBeToday = 1 And DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0) THEN
            --PREV DAY IS TODAY, USE DAY FROM LAST WEEK
            @LastWeekThu
        ELSE
            --PREV DAY SELECT
            DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0)
    END

SET @DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST = DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) + -(4); --Mon + 4 = 5 = Friday
SELECT @PrevFri =
    CASE
        WHEN @DontAllowPrevToBeToday = 1 And DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0) THEN
            --PREV DAY IS TODAY, USE DAY FROM LAST WEEK
            @LastWeekFri
        ELSE
            --PREV DAY SELECT
            DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0)
    END

SET @DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST = DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) + -(5); --Mon + 5 = 6 = Saturday
SELECT @PrevSat =
    CASE
        WHEN @DontAllowPrevToBeToday = 1 And DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0) THEN
            --PREV DAY IS TODAY, USE DAY FROM LAST WEEK
            @LastWeekSat
        ELSE
            --PREV DAY SELECT
            DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0)
    END

SET @DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST = DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) + -(6); --Mon + 6 = 7 = Sunday
SELECT @PrevSun =
    CASE
        WHEN @DontAllowPrevToBeToday = 1 And DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME) = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0) THEN
            --PREV DAY IS TODAY, USE DAY FROM LAST WEEK
            @LastWeekSun
        ELSE
            --PREV DAY SELECT
            DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @DATE_TIME - (@DAY_SPECIFIC_ADJUST) %7), 0)
    END

SELECT @PrevMon as PrevMon, @PrevTue as PrevTue, @PrevWed as PrevWed, @PrevThu as PrevThu, @PrevFri as PrevFri, @PrevSat as PrevSat, @PrevSun as PrevSun
```

Is this sound and is there a simpler way to achieve this?  I'm sure there has to be, but I'm stumped.

Thank you for your help and feedback!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**
This is essentially a long comment, but posted as answer since it involves a decent amount of code and commentary.

From [How to get the last run job details in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310616/how-to-get-the-last-run-job-details-in-sql), by @deeg.

```
SELECT  t2.instance_id
            ,t1.name as JobName
            ,t2.step_id as StepID
            ,t2.step_name as StepName
            ,CONVERT(CHAR(10), CAST(STR(t2.run_date,8, 0) AS DATETIME), 111) as RunDate
            ,STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST ( t2.run_time AS VARCHAR(6 ) ) ,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') as RunTime
            ,t2.run_duration
            ,CASE t2.run_status WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
                                WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded' 
                                WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry' 
                                WHEN 3 THEN 'Cancelled' 
                                WHEN 4 THEN 'In Progress' 
                                END as ExecutionStatus
            ,t2.message as MessageGenerated    
    FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs t1
    JOIN    msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory t2
            ON t1.job_id = t2.job_id   
            --Join to pull most recent job activity per job, not job step
    JOIN    (
            SELECT  TOP 1
                    t1.job_id
                    ,t1.start_execution_date
                    ,t1.stop_execution_date
            FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity t1
            --If no job_id detected, return last run job
            ORDER 
            BY      last_executed_step_date DESC
            ) t3
            --Filter on the most recent job_id
            ON t1.job_id = t3.job_Id
            --Filter out job steps that do not fall between start_execution_date and stop_execution_date
            AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), t2.run_date, 112) + ' ' 
            + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), t2.run_time), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'), 121)  
            BETWEEN t3.start_execution_date AND t3.stop_execution_date
```

Would give you all the jobs that ran between the start and stop execution dates (change as needed). If **Job A** succeeded where the datediff between the RunDate (and/or RunTime) was within seven days. Then run **Job B**.

aka... where `t2.JobName = 'yourjob'` and `t2.run_status = 1`, then run Job B.

Would this sort of logic help? Note that you can filter out what comes back to get rid of the individual steps if necessary.